# Passing value of dropdown to angular js

Tags: angularjs

I wish to set the value of my dropdown and the value of my textbox in *ng-model* to pass it to my *angular js*.

The console displays *null* for the value of my dropdown.

What I've tried:

```
<form id="uploadForm">
   <div id="republishSingle" class="panel-collapse collapse in desc vertical" style="text-align: left">
      <div class="horizontal">
         <div class="dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="selectSource1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" ng-model="republishSource">
            Source system
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
               <h5 class="dropdown-header">Source system</h5>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="s1">S1</a>
               <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-value="s2">S2</a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-5">
            <input class="form-control disableButton" id="policy" type="text" placeholder="Policy" ng-model="republishInput"/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <div class="form-group" aria-label="file upload">
               <input id="republish" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
                  ng-click="doRepublish(republishSource,republishInput)" value="Republish"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The `ng-model` directive is not valid on a `<button>`. I'm not sure what UI framework you are using, but that dropdown looks weird. This isn't some jQuery dropdown, is it?

Comment: A bootstrap based dropdown Lex. Used Angular along with that.

Comment: It's not going to work with Angular. You need to use the [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) version that was built specifically for AngularJS.

Comment: Oh. Thank you Lex. Will use that.